# Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined other error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So I go the error Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined. I looked around for a solution to this error. It seems like all of the answers to this question were something like 'jQuery needs to be the first script'. The thing is that my jQuery is my first script. My code looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>


    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Inventory </title>
    <style>
    //my styles
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="jquery.json-2.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    //my html
    <script> 
              function updateInv() {

            var i=0;
            var fail = 0;
            for(i=0; i < itemttl; i++)
            {

                var hill = 500000 + i;
                var available = document.getElementById(hill).innerHTML;



                if (available < 0) 
                {
                  fail = 1;
                }
            }

            if (fail==0)
            {
                alert('start');
                var TableData;

                TableData = $.toJSON(storeTblValues());
                alert('here');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "processJSONarray.php",
            data: "pTableData=" + TableData,
            success: function(msg){
                // return value stored in msg variable
            }
        });
                alert('Inventory was Updated');
            }

            else
            {
                alert('Not enough inventory available');
            }

      }

      function storeTblValues()
      {
        alert('1');
        var TableData = new Array();
        var i=0;
        var eq = 200000 + i;
        var skuId = 600000 + i;
        for(i=0; i < itemttl; i++)
        {
            eq = 200000 + i;
            skuId = 600000 + i;
            TableData[i]={
                "sku" : document.getElementById(skuId).innerHTML
                , "inv" : document.getElementById(eq).innerHTML
            }

        }
        //TableData.shift();
        return TableData;
      }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: I have also put the  right after  and right before the first . All of them had the same error. So do i still have it in the wrong spot or is ther a different error?

Comment: `jquery.json-2.4.min.js` is not the jQuery library. It's something else.

Comment: Could you show us/provide a link to your `jquery.json-2.4.min.js` file?

Comment: I agree with @Pointy, your js file is most likely not jquery. Run `alert(window.jQuery == true)` in console to check if its loaded. If the popup is false then its not there.

Comment: you're referring to a jquery plugin.

Comment: @Pointy How can you know that for sure? I mean it's a relative path ; ).

Comment: @Teemu Of course, it could be jQuery, but I've got a sharp Occam's Razor here. There's at least one (probably old) JSON library for jQuery floating around out there, and I bet that's one of them. Note that there is no version 2.4 of jQuery.

Comment: @Pointy Haa... got you ; ). You (and Quentin) are most likely right, my comment was actually an attempt (maybe a poor-one?) to add some humor on this serious site.

Comment: @Teemu well I wasn't sure, and there may be young innocent people reading these comments someday :)

Comment: Yes this error was because of my lack of knowledge on jQuery. Did not realize that you had to have the jQeury library with the plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> <script src="jquery.json-2.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
> ```

This is not loading jQuery successfully. It is possible that it is giving you a 404 or other error, but the filename suggests that it points to the JSON plugin for jQuery and not to jQuery itself.

You can get jQuery from [the jQuery website](http://jquery.com/download/).

Answer (score 1):

Try using this in your script tag instead. Or alternatively Nuget Jquery and include it much like you are doing so now.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.js"></script>
```